# Ray picking - get direction from pitch and yaw

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl, picking

I am attempting to cast a ray from the center of the screen and check for collisions with objects.

When rendering, I use these calls to set up the camera:

```
GL11.glRotated(mPitch, 1, 0, 0);
GL11.glRotated(mYaw, 0, 1, 0);
GL11.glTranslated(mPositionX, mPositionY, mPositionZ);
```

I am having trouble creating the ray, however. This is the code I have so far:

```
ray.origin = new Vector(mPositionX, mPositionY, mPositionZ);
ray.direction = new Vector(?, ?, ?);
```

My question is: what should I put in the question mark spots? I.e. how can I create the ray direction from the pitch and roll?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat this as a conversion from [spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates).

Assuming the ray should have some length `r`, your `x`, `y`, and `z` components can be calculated like this:

```
x = r * sin(mPitch) * cos(mYaw)
y = r * sin(mPitch) * sin(mYaw)
z = r * cos(mPitch)
```